# Programmatically check for Updates on IMAP-Server like e.g. Outlook does

Tags: imap

I don't understand the IMAP-Protocol documentation well enough to understand how to solve my question:

I built an app, that stores all contents of an IMAP Server mailbox in a database. That works great.

Now I want to store only the updates on the IMAP Server without reading 10-thousand of messages again.

Outlook and other mail clients are getting their updates nearly in real time. Which seems to me, that there is a kind of push service, which I cannot find in the documentation.

Even important to me: Updates in very old messages, that could have been changed, moved or deleted.

Thank you for any hint.

The current read is done by fetching UIDs. I start from the highest. This allows to read new messages but no updates on older ones.